# hello would like to know how to fix the error mysql connect

Tags: mysql, connection

I put my website online as centerdownload.net but when I created a mysql database appears an error in the browser on all pages:

> Warning: mysql_connect () [function.mysql-connect]: Can not get
>   hostname for your address in / home / centerdo / public_html /
>   Connections / postagens.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Can not get hostname for your address in / home /
>   centerdo / public_html / Connections / postagens.php on line 9

There is nothing wrong in line 9 that he was wrong dreamweaver warned and besides is the bank that is locally zens works on my pc now when I go on my site by the nevegador trim the unfortunate mistake, how do to fix it?
between the following site you will see the error.

http://www.centerdownload.net/

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually your hostname should be `localhost`

If the database is in the same server as the website itself.

If not, then only you should put the actual address. Please let me know what you put as your hostname.